# Can you sent Spring Batch commit-interval from JobParameters or configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm trying to set up a Spring Batch XML-based configuration that uses chunk-oriented processing. I don't want to hard-code the commit interval because for my application, it is more appropriate to allow this value to be set from the `JobParameters` or, as a less desirable alternative, from a Spring `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Can I do this? How?

Comment: Maybe related: https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-1396

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sure just use

```
<step id="chunkOrientedStep">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk 
            reader="itemReader"
            writer="itemWriter" 
            commit-interval="#{jobParameters['commit.interval']}">
        </chunk>
    </tasklet>
</step>
```